# How to traverse an unknown-length path in SurrealDB?

Tags: surrealdb

I want to recursively follow related records in SurrealDB, and I can't find the syntax to express it.

The simplest explanation of my goal is Neo4j/Cypher's [variable length pattern matches](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/patterns/#cypher-pattern-varlength). More generally, I want to start at a record and follow particular relations until I stop (either by number of steps or some other condition), where I don't know how many relation steps are needed between start and end.

The closest I can find is discussed [here](https://surrealdb.com/docs/surrealql), in the section on 'No JOINs'. This doesn't fill my need, because the query specifies the number of steps between start and end. I'm imagining something like `SELECT {->parent->person REPEATED 1..5} FROM person:tobie`, which would find all of tobie's ancestors for 5 generations (`person:tobie->parent->person`, `person:tobie->parent->person->parent->person`, etc).

If this isn't part of SurrealQL's features, can you give me hints on other ways to get the same result? I've considered using the [scripting functions](https://surrealdb.com/docs/surrealql/functions/script), which seems powerful but off the beaten path.

Comment: So even though they market it as a all-in-1 solution they don't support enough graph traversal features to be able to brand themselves as "also a graph database"... As a graph database it's simply useless. Compare it with ArangoDB where you can easily do what you want and even access all the nodes in the path by index.. There's no good way to achieve that in surrealdb, sorry. I gave up  and went back to ArangoDB - a shame it doesn't work well a also a graph database, since they do have some nice things going also.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the depth you want to traverse (surrealDB has an internal limit for recursive queries) you can use custom functions recursively :

something in the likes should work (I personally use something similar, but with records links) :

```
DEFINE FUNCTION fn::traverse_recurse($el: record) {
    $parent = SELECT ->parent->person FROM $el;
    return if ($parent is not none) then
        return array::concat([$parent], fn::traverse_recurse($parent))
    else
        return []
    end;
};

SELECT *, fn::traverse_recurse($this.id) as ancestry from person:tobie;
```